# Simplify a proposition of logic: $p ∨ (p ∧ (\lnot p ∧ q ∨ r ∧ (p ∧ r)))$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to come up with some concrete simplification for the following proposition:

> $$p ∨ (p ∧ (\lnot p ∧ q ∨ r ∧ (p ∧ r)))$$

Any ideas on what is the resulting form?

Comment: What is the truth value when $p$ is true? And when $p$ is false?

Comment: To make the statement unambiguous, you should specify whether $\lor$ precedes over $\land$ or vice versa (though I surmise from your brackets that $\land$ precedes over $\lor$).

Answer (score 9):

I'll touch on a comment left below another answer:

> I can manipulate $p∨(p∧\varphi)$ a lot using distributivity, but I ran in circles when I tried to drop $\varphi$ using simple rules.

Let's take a look at a [truth-table](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p%20OR%20%28p%20AND%20phi%29) for $p \lor(p \land \varphi)$, and compare those truth values, with the truth value assignment column for $p$:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

(Truth-table image compliments to WolframAlpha). We see that $p \equiv p \lor (p \land \varphi)$, and can justify the equivalence by merely considering each of the possible $4$ truth value assignments for $p$ and $\phi$, i.e., we have a proof-by-cases.

Now, if we let $\varphi = \lnot p ∧ q ∨ r ∧ (p ∧ r)$, then we have $$p ∨ (p ∧ (\lnot p ∧ q ∨ r ∧ (p ∧ r))) \equiv p \lor (p \land \varphi) \equiv p$$

Comment: Nice write-up, table and explanation +1

Comment: From Wolfram|Alpha terms page: "It is permitted to use and post individual, incidental results or small groups of results from Wolfram|Alpha on non-commercial websites and blogs, provided those results are properly credited to Wolfram|Alpha". I like your answer, but please attribute that picture!

Comment: Thanks, @dtldarek The attribution was indeed neglected (and now rectified). Thanks for caring enough to comment accordingly! ;-)

Comment: I actually ment proof it non-semantically. The answer is good in any case.

Comment: @NickKidman Are you the OP? If so, try to stick to one account ;-). Do you think you can extend the idea used here to a non-semantic proof?  It follows pretty much from the definitions of the connectives.

Answer (score 4):

If $p$ is true, the statement is true. If $p$ is false the statement is false. From this we conclude the statement$\iff$$p$, so the statement is equivalent to $p$.

Comment: That's right. Can you formalize it without natural deduction? I can manipulate $p\lor (p\land\phi)$ a lot using distributivity, but I ran in circles when I tried to drop $\phi$ using simple rules.

Comment: @NickKidman To formalize it without natural deduction you can use functioral variables of one argument (an offshoot of Lesniewski's protothetic... which has functioral variables of multiple arguments also).  See the section of Arthur Prior's Formal Logic called something like "And Functioral Variables".

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- Let $f_{\alpha}(p) = p \lor (p \land \alpha)$, show that $f_\alpha$ does not depend on $\alpha$, that is, $f_\alpha(p) = p$.
- This behaves much like $g_\beta(x) = \max(x,\min(x,\beta))$, i.e. $g_\beta(x) \leq x$ because of minimum and $g_\beta(x) \geq x$ because of maximum, hence $g_\beta(x) = x$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$